# Image orientation is changed on ImageView When fetching from Gallery and upload

Tags: java, android, image, rotation, screen-orientation

I simply want to fetch Images from gallery and upload then download from Server and set it on an ImageView on Activity. The image View is placed at the center of the Activity. All is working fine just a screenOrientation variation problem with adjusting Image on ImageView after fetching it from Server, download and set to image View. Please have a look over code what i am using to download Image Bitmap from Server and set it to required ImageView. It usually display rotated Image in case of portrait capturing image from Gallery or Camera. Please let me know if i am missing anything in my Code.

```
package com.fedorvlasov.lazylist;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.WeakHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import com.example.qlique.R;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class ImageLoader {
    MemoryCache memoryCache = new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews = Collections
            .synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService;
    Handler handler = new Handler();// handler to display images in UI thread

    public ImageLoader(Context context) {
        fileCache = new FileCache(context);
        executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

    final int stub_id = R.drawable.stub;

    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap = memoryCache.get(url);
        if (bitmap != null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView) {
        PhotoToLoad p = new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) {
        File f = fileCache.getFile(url);

        // from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if (b != null)
            return b;

        // from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap = null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) imageUrl
                    .openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            conn.disconnect();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            if (ex instanceof OutOfMemoryError)
                memoryCache.clear();
            return null;
        }
    }

    // decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f) {
        try {
            // decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            FileInputStream stream1 = new FileInputStream(f);
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream1, null, o);
            stream1.close();

            // Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE = 70;
            int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;
            int scale = 1;
            while (true) {
                if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE
                        || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp /= 2;
                height_tmp /= 2;
                scale *= 2;
            }

            // decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize = scale;
            FileInputStream stream2 = new FileInputStream(f);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(stream2, null, o2);
            stream2.close();
            return bitmap;
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    // Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;

        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i) {
            url = u;
            imageView = i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
            this.photoToLoad = photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                Bitmap bmp = getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
                memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
                if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                    return;
                BitmapDisplayer bd = new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
                handler.post(bd);
            } catch (Throwable th) {
                th.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad) {
        String tag = imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if (tag == null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    // Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
            bitmap = b;
            photoToLoad = p;
        }

        public void run() {
            if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            if (bitmap != null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            else
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First check the `Orientation` of an Image

```
public static int getExifOrientation(String filepath) {
                int degree = 0;
                ExifInterface exif = null;
                try {
                        exif = new ExifInterface(filepath);
                } catch (IOException ex) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                }
                if (exif != null) {
                        int orientation = exif.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, -1);
                        if (orientation != -1) {
                                // We only recognise a subset of orientation tag values.
                                switch (orientation) {
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                                        degree = 90;
                                        break;
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                                        degree = 180;
                                        break;
                                case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                                        degree = 270;
                                        break;
                                }

                        }
                }

                return degree;
        }
```

***And Rotate the angle of Bitmap to that Degree.***

```
Bitmap bitmap = YOUR_BITMAP;
    //rotate bitmap
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();               
    matrix.postRotate(orientation);
    //create new rotated bitmap
    bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0,bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);  
   YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

Answer (score 0):

One nice online tool to view the Orientation and the details EXIF information http://metapicz.com/#exif-box.

It would be good if you can fix/reset the orientation at the server side(once per image) and alternatively fixing at the client side is a bit costly ( as this conversion to happen every time )